# Is there a possibility to change the position of the content inside my header?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm currently playing around with Angular and Clarity Design.
I got my basic layout now, though I have one question.

Is there a possibility to change the position of the content inside my header area?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/KelTWxK]

This is what it looks like right now.

```css
.title {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.header-1 {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/img/...">

<header class="header-1">
    <div class="branding">
        <a routerLink="/home" class="nav-link">
            <img src = "/assets/img/..." style = "width:70px;height:100px">
            <span class="title">...</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav" [clr-nav-level]="1">
        <a routerLink="/verwaltung" class="nav-link nav-icon">
            <clr-icon shape="administrator" size ="36"></clr-icon>
        </a>
        <a routerLink="/downloads" class="nav-link nav-icon">
            <clr-icon shape="download" size ="36"></clr-icon>
        </a>
        <a routerLink="/entwicklung" class="nav-link nav-icon">
            <clr-icon shape="terminal" size ="36"></clr-icon>
        </a>
        <a routerLink="/crm" class="nav-link nav-icon">
            <clr-icon shape="cloud" size ="36"></clr-icon>
        </a>
    </div>
    <form class="search">
        <label for="search_input">
            <input id="search_input" size ="64" type="text" placeholder="Suche nach Begriffen...">
        </label>
    </form>
    <div class="header-actions">
        <clr-dropdown>
            <button class="nav-icon" clrDropdownTrigger>
                <clr-icon shape="user"></clr-icon>
                <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
            </button>
            <clr-dropdown-menu *clrIfOpen clrPosition="bottom-right">
                <a routerLink="/kontakt" clrDropdownItem>Kontakt</a>
                <a routerLink="/ausloggen" clrDropdownItem>Ausloggen</a>
            </clr-dropdown-menu>
        </clr-dropdown>
    </div>
</header>
```

I would like to move the buttons and the search bar more down so it looks like its placed central inside the header.

I don't want to change the height of the header though

Comment: The image is not helping us. You need to post the relevant code so we can help you out.

Comment: I was able to solve it by including it into my header.css
Thank you for your input!

Comment: Just for curiosity, where did you put those css line before including them into your `header.css`?

Comment: I did add the already named css styles into my header.css. I didn't know I could simply adress each button as its own

Answer (score 0):

You are already changing the default size of the header with your additional padding, so you'll have to apply the padding to all of the elements to make them centered or give them a larger line-height to equalize the heights. There are a lot of ways with CSS to do this, but you're on your own since you're overriding the Clarity styles.